# Handling missing sequential periods of time series data

Tags: time-series, missing-data

I have monthly time series data from Jan 2019 to Jul 2023.
I have seen different ways of dealing with missing data that occurs sporadically through the dataset but what to do if I am missing a 6-month period?

For example, I have data from Jan 2019 to Mar 2020, then Oct 2020 to Jul 2023.

I could simply start the dataset from Oct 2020, but am wondering if mean or median imputation might be acceptable here? (however, after the first period of mean imputation (Apr 2020), the average for the next month (May 2020) would include observed and estimated data).